# Is it possible to observe mobx-state-tree events for a specific map entry

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

Is it possible to do something like so:

```
observe(props.store.zone.players[props.socket_id], (change) => {

  ...

})
```

I want to listen to events on each specific instance of the component.

Here's the Zone store:

```
const ZoneState = types
  .model({
    name: types.optional(types.string, ""),
    players: types.map(PlayerState),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    syncPlayer(params) {
      const player = self.players.get(params.id);
      const oldPlayerData = toJS(player);
      self.players.put(params);
    },

  }));
```

And the player store

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const PlayerState = types
  .model({
    id: types.identifier,
    socket_id: types.optional(types.string, ""),
    x: types.integer,
    z: types.integer,
    name: types.optional(types.string, "Unknown One"),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    sync(params) {
      self.x = params.x;
      self.z = params.z;
    },
  }));

export default PlayerState;
```

Comment: Yes, you could e.g. use either [`observe` or `autorun` to run some code when a specific map entry changes](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-waterfall-doxlo?file=/src/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. use either [`observe`](https://mobx.js.org/intercept-and-observe.html#observe) or [`autorun`](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html#autorun) to run some code when a specific map entry changes.

**Example**

```js
// ...

const zoneState = ZoneState.create();

zoneState.syncPlayer({ id: "1", socket_id: "1", x: 1, z: 2, name: "test" });

observe(zoneState.players.get("1"), (change) => {
  console.log("observe", change);
});

autorun(() => {
  console.log("autorun", zoneState.players.get("1"));
});

zoneState.syncPlayer({ id: "1", socket_id: "1", x: 1, z: 2, name: "test 2" });
```